# launching a ps1 file within a ps1 tool

Tags: powershell, user-interface, launch

Hi i have created a tool which launches central troubleshooting apps, but i have recently created another tool ps1 file and i cannot seem to get it to launch from the other tool

```
function LaunchQuickNotes {

try { 
    Start-Process -filePath "\\c\s\CAF1\ITSC Second Line Support\Craig Heckles Team\GUI\Admin Tool\QuickNotes Tool\QuickNotes tool - Tier 1.ps1" -
    LogWrite "Quick Notes launched" 
} 
catch {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("Unable to launch Quick Notes.",0,"Error",0)
}
```

i it seems to just open the .txt file and not launch in powershell.

Any suggestions

Comment: Call the function `LaunchQuickNotes` in order to launch it.

Comment: The function is called LaunchQuickNotes?

Comment: i call the function with  $btn_QuickNotes.Add_Click({LaunchQuickNotes})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
Start-Process -filePath "\\c\s\CAF1\ITSC Second Line Support\Craig Heckles Team\GUI\Admin Tool\QuickNotes Tool\QuickNotes tool - Tier 1.ps1" -
```

try

```
powershell.exe -f "\\c\s\CAF1\ITSC Second Line Support\Craig Heckles Team\GUI\Admin Tool\QuickNotes Tool\QuickNotes tool - Tier 1.ps1"
```

Comment: please mark the the answer as solution if it helped resolve your issue.